# problems with gnuplot in 14.10

Tags: gnuplot

some of the useful terminal types (wxt or qt) do not exist.  With previous versions of gnuplot and ubuntu, wxt worked well.  However, Debian apparently dropped support for wxWidgets 2.8, so gnuplot no longer has an option for the wxt terminal type.  Can this be fixed, or qt be supported?